# Dynamic components in array dont rerender (building dynamic components from elements description in json)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, dynamic

lets say I have input (simplified) like this

```
[
  {
    type: "text",
    text: "how are you {name}"
  },
  {
    type: "input",
    input: "name"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    text: "good to hear that {name}"
  },
  {
    type: "input",
    input: "age"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    text: "you are {age} years old"
  }
]
```

I am receiving an array of elements, which I want to build into simple html structure, lets say we only have Texts and Inputs. This structure should build into:

```
How are you {this should contain the same value  as (name) input}
<input (name) />
Good to hear that {this should contain the same value  as (name) input}
<input (age) />
you are {this should contain the same value as (age) input}
```

I need to build all of this dynamically, from array I receive. It can contain any number of texts/inputs, in any order, i need to "bind them together"

I do have working solution, here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-change-array?file=DynamicComponent.tsx

i can describe it here as well

```
const [variables, setVariables] = useState<{ [key: string]: any }>({}); // Extracting all variables
const [jsxArray, setJsxArray] = useState([]);  // dynamic array of JSX elements

useEffect(() => {
  extractVariables();
}, []); // extract variables from data array

useEffect(() => {
  buildArray();
}, [variables]); 
.....
function buildArray() {...} // this function set jsxArray to new Array with <MyDynamicInputs> and<MyDynamicText>
.....
return <React.Fragment>{jsxArray.map(x => x)}</React.Fragment>;
```

However this solution always redraw whole array. Is there a way I wouldnt have to build the whole array every time, just to let react control all the input a text fields? **I am creating component with variables as props, variables are changing but react doesnt change those components Ive put into the array** Why is that?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-array-doesn-rerender?file=DynamicComponent.tsx

```
const [variables, setVariables] = useState<{ [key: string]: any }>({});
const [jsxArray, setJsxArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const vars = extractVariables();
  buildArray(vars);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("variables changing");
}, [variables]); // variables changing but jsx array doesnt

function buildArray() {...} // this function set jsxArray to new Array with <MyDynamicInputs> and<MyDynamicText>

return <React.Fragment>{jsxArray.map(x => x)}</React.Fragment>; // no Change on its own
```

I do have a working solution (which rerenders whole array) but i would like to ask if i am using react wrong and why is the second example not changing text components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing seems a bit weird, you *should* update the whole array every time. Maybe consider drawing array right in jsx without keeping it in `useState`, this just doesn't make much sense in react. If you are concerned about performance, don't be, react is ridiculously fast. Also constructing array in JSX doesn't mean that it will be drawn every time in DOM. React will only redraw elements that actually changed, so it will interact with DOM only as many times as is absolutely necessary, this is why it's so fast.

So a solution I would suggest and the way such things are supposed to be written in react is as such:

```
function MyDynamicComponent({ testData }) {
  const [variables, setVariables] = useState<Record<string, any>>(() => {
    // Passing function to "useState", there is no point of extracting
    // variables in "useEffect" if you never update them when testData
    // changes. If you actually want to do this, then you can move this back to
    // to useEffect, but it would probably be nicer not to create a function 
    // in the middle of the component, but to just move all logic inside "useEffect",
    // anyway you never reuse this function, there is not much point in it
    const newVars: Record<string, any> = {};
    for (const el of testData) {
      if (el.type === "input") {
        newVars[el.input] = "";
      }
    }
    console.log(newVars);
    return newVars;
  })

  // Now just render array in JSX as react documentation suggests
  return (
    // React.Fragment shortcut doesn't seem to work in stackblitz, not sure about
    // your IDE, you can replace it back with <React.Fragment>
    <>
      {testData.map((el, i) => {
        if (el.type === "text") {
          let text = el.text
          // If you care about performance too much, you could just
          // replace this with for..in loop without Object.keys
          for (const inputVar of Object.keys(variables)) {
            // By replacing occurences of variable you could use multiple
            // variables in one text
            text = text.replace("{" + inputVar + "}", variables[inputVar])
            // If you care about performance too much you could break the loop here
          }
          return <p key={i}>{text}</p>
        } else {
          return (
            <MyDynamicInput
              key={i}
              varName={el.input}
              variables={variables}
              setVariables={setVariables}
            />
          );
        }
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Simple and fast enough. Sorry that I'm suggesting a completely different solution instead of solving the problem that you asked, maybe I'm completely wrong, but sometimes the problem you have is not really a problem and you only think it's a problem because you don't consider other solutions. If you render array like this you will never have any issues with components not updating or whatever

Comment: yeah i have recently ran some more experiments and as you said, i didnt realized that " Also constructing array in JSX doesn't mean that it will be drawn every time in DOM" thats the answer i was looking for. By the way, do you have some favourite resources for going a bit deeper with someone's understanding of react?

Comment: @Dan, well, personally I didn't use any special resources when learning, most topics are describes pretty well in react documentation, it has articles for most situations you will encounter, if you need something particular and can't find it there, then google almost certainly has some articles to help. I'd just advice to remember the three rules of optimization https://course.ccs.neu.edu/cs5010f17/Slides/08-Efficiency-Lessons/theRulesOfOptimization.html. React is very fast, combining this with modern computational powers, you get the idea

Comment: Also not sure if you are aware, but `useEffect` calls run asynchronously after the component first rendered, so if you update state inside them, component will rerender. This is no big deal in the snippet in your question, but this may lead to flashing on screen because the state updated 100ms after the page first rendered empty